# GridView delete not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using a `GridView` in C#.NET 3.5 and have just converted the underlying `DataSource` from `Adapter` model to an object which gets its data from LINQ to SQL - i.e. a Business object that `returns` a `List<>` for the `GetData()` function etc.

All was well in Denmark and the `Update`, and conditional `Select` statements work as expected but I can't get the `Delete` function to work. Just trying to pass in the ID or the entire object but it's being passed in a **"new"** object with none of the properties set. I'm just wondering if it's the old `OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"` monster in the `ObjectDataSource` causing confusion again.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried checking if your delete command is being fired at all, with SQL Profiler or some profiler tool?

Comment: Yes - the delete function is being called in the business layer but the object being passed in is an "empty" object - i.e. it's not null but the members of the object are nulls and zeros.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution. I had to set the GridView's DataKeyNames property to the unique key that my data was returning (in this case a classically named ID field). I'm guessing that this property "unset" itself when the Grid refreshed.